# how to simulate Sent_Protocl_signal?

Tags: simulink, stm32

I wanted to simulate the Sent_Protocol with an STM32 μC emulate as if I had a sensor. and represent this with an oscilloscope . I have to simulate this on Matlab and then connect with STM32. so i thought the signal should be like a normal PWM Signal look like.

So I wanted to ask if it is possible to generate a different pulse width in the same signal as in the above [image: Sent_Frame] picture ?